# Decrypting defuse/php-encryption Crypto::encryptWithPassword() in Java

Tags: java, php, encryption, cryptography

I have a PHP application that store some sensitive information in a MySQL database. To protect this information, I use the [defuse/php-encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) library's `Crypto::encryptWithPassword()` method like this:

```
<?php

// ... get sensitive data from user ...

$encrypted = base64_encode(Crypto::encryptWithPassword($sensitive, $password, true));

// ... store that data in database ...
```

I also have another Java application that need to access this information. However, I don't know how I could decrypt that from Java. Here's the code that I've tried:

```
byte[] encrypted = DB.getThatEncryptedData();
byte[] salt = Arrays.copyOfRange(encrypted, 4, 35);

String password = SomewhereSafe.getThePassword();
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 100000, 32);
SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
SecretKey secret = keyFactory.generateSecret(spec);

Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret);
byte[] decrypted = c.doFinal(encrypted);
```

However, when I ran that code, I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 4 bytes
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineGetKeySize(AESCipher.java:495)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.passCryptoPermCheck(Cipher.java:1067)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1025)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:801)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:864)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1249)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1186)
    at com.example.test.app.Decrypt.main(Decrypt.java:24)
```

What is the correct way to decrypt that data?

Comment: "Invalid AES key length: 4 bytes" huh?

Comment: Ahhhh... looks like I didn't generate the key correctly. Thanks! Will update the question after I found the right way.